# Does string.Replace("a", "b") automatically check if "a" exists?

Tags: c#, string, replace, contains

```
string banana = "banana apple";
banana.Replace("apple", "pie");
```

If I want to replace apple with pie, can I do it like that, or do I need to use the following?

```
if(banana.Contains("apple"))
    banana.Replace("apple", "pie");
```

Comment: What do you expect would happen if you try to replace a substring which does not exist? It throws an exception? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: I think what the OP wants to ask is if he needs to check whether the string is null before replacing it. The question is yes, or it will throw an exception (even if the string is empty). you can use StringBuilder to replace without having to check. Also, you have to reassign the new replaced string to the old string if you're not using a StringBuilder

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You just have to read [msdn:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ( or try it out yourself )

> Return Value Type: System.String A string that is equivalent to the
>   current string except that all instances of oldValue are replaced with
>   newValue. **If oldValue is not found in the current instance, the method
>   returns the current instance unchanged.**

Side-note: since strings are immutable(you cannot change the instance) you have to reassign a new string if you want to change the old:

```
banana = banana.Replace("apple", "pie");
```

Comment: Well that answered my question perfectly, thank you.